# Changing how zathura-pdf-mupdf render epub files

Tags: epub, zathura

I am transitioning from cool reader to zathura as my reader but I don't like how the epub was rendered. I can do some basic changes like the background and text color with my zathurarc file but it can not do much with regards to the rendering of the epub like margin, spacing, fonts and etc. Is there a way to change how the epub was rendered?

Here is a screenshot, the one on the left is coolreader while the other is zathura. I would like to have them look as close as possible like the fonts, justification, margins and etc.

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: Sorry for the late respon, but I have shared a screenshot of my current state and what I would like to acheive

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to configure Zathura, but most of what you wanted is available in [Foliate](http://johnfactotum.github.io/foliate/), which is free and open source. The book (The Art of Data Science) is legally available for free.

By default,it looks somewhat different.
[image]
However, after changing the window size, font (to Times New Roman, available in **Menu -> Font**), background color (**Menu -> Theme** use one of the default theme, or select your favorite colors to create one), and font color (**Menu -> Themes**), I was able to achieve a similar look. The black margins at the sides (which is in your screenshot) is not available in Foliate, but the margin size can be changed and the margins will have the same color as the background.

[image]

It also auto hides the headerbar (this behavior can be changed)

It is available in different formats

- **snap** `sudo snap install foliate`
- **flatpak** `flatpak install flathub com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate`
- **PPA**

```
sudo add-apt repository ppa:apandada1/foliate
sudo apt update
sudo apt install foliate
```

Disclaimer: I maintain the PPA of Foliate, but I am not affiliated with its development.

Comment: I am not finding for alternatives it is just because I would like to change how zathura formats epub. I would rather want to stick with zathura mainly because it is lightweight, can open both pdf and epub, and also able to accept pipes from standard input which fits nicely with my workflow. Edit: And I have also used Foliate before switching to Cool Reader but having a gtk application on a mostly qt based setup gives some overhead and sticks out like a sore thumb

Comment: @Jerico You can also open an issue at the development webpage of Zathura and ask this question there https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura . I just wanted to mention Foliate as an alternative because I know how to configure it, but I am not familiar with Zathura (Foliate blends well in my KDE setup despite being a GTK application. Zathura is also a GTK application, by the way).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, guess I'll try opening a thread